# Guardar frames/ images de um video

Tags: java, imagem, javafx, processamento-de-imagens

Olá,

Preciso e guardar imagens/ frames de um video.
A ideia é criar uma pré-visualização do filme antes de ele começar.

O problema é que não estou a conseguir implementar os exemplos que encontrei.

1º Exemplo tirar um screenshot do componente com JavaFX, funciona mas o vídeo tem de estar a reproduzir.

Código:

```
...
    // 
    private void saveAsPng(Node n) {
        WritableImage image = n.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
        // TODO: probably use a file chooser here
        File file = new File("D:\\movie12.png");

        try {
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possível capturar imagem do video");
        }
    }
...
```

2º Fazendo uso das Librarias de JavaCV ou Xuggler parece ser possivel mas nem com uma nem com outra estou a conseguir.

**JavaCV**

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ZzzzzzzSaveImgFromVideo{
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException, Exception
    {
        FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("D:\\Movie..................mp4");
        frameGrabber.start();
        IplImage i;
        try {

            i = frameGrabber.grab();
            BufferedImage  bi = i.getBufferedImage();
            ImageIO.write(bi,"png", new File("D:/Img.png"));
            frameGrabber.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

erro:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at zzzzzzzsaveimgfromvideo.ZzzzzzzSaveImgFromVideo.main(ZzzzzzzSaveImgFromVideo.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22107132/3792998

não estou a usar Maven:

Livrarias adicionadas ao projeto:
`javacpp` `javacv`

questões:

- Alguém sabe quais as bibliotecas que são necessárias para por a
  funciona o javaCV?
- É necessário já ter instalado no PC OpenCV ou não    tem nada a ver?
- Algum código mais pratico para o que pretendo fazer?

Comment: Pelo erro `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer` é falta de uma classe/pacote, compilou via linha de comando? Se sim tente usar assim `java -cp nome-do-pacote.jar`

Comment: Se não esta usando Maven qual você esta usando? Gradle, Sbt ou linha de comando?

Comment: não, ainda não compilei via cmd... estou a usar o NetBeans e insiro as bibliotecas diretamente. Mas neste caso não estou a conseguir.

Comment: Mas o projeto no Netbeans usa Maven ou Gradle? Por que geralmente é adicionado no projeto estas libs, ou você nem chegou a adicionar?

Comment: Eu adicionei diretamente as libs no projeto (sem usar Maven ou Gradle). link: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv#manual-installation - adicionei as que diz aqui

Comment: Confere aí se adicionou todos os jars, no caso é o `javacpp.jar`. Outra coisa, pelos comentários do post que você linkou, o modo de conseguir o `BufferedImage` é diferente nas versões mais recentes. Veja também se na hora de executar os mesmos jars estão no classpath.

Comment: @Dudaskank sim eu tenho a lib `javacpp.jar` inserida, já a atualizei por outra mas o problema continua, o erro resulta quando tento criar o `FFmpegFrameGrabber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplo utilizando Xuggle para gerar imagens de um vídeo e redimensiona-las passando o caminho dele e o intervalo de segundos entre os frames:

```
public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 1;
private static final int IMG_WIDTH = 300;
private static final int IMG_HEIGHT = 225;

String fileName = "video_path";

IMediaReader mediaReader = null;
mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(fileName);
mediaReader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
mediaReader.addListener(new ImageSnapListener());
while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null)
   do {} while(false);



/**
 * Classe auxiliar para gerar imagem do arquivo vídeo
 * de upload
 * @author allan-braga
 *
 */
private  class ImageSnapListener extends MediaListenerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {
            String outputFilename = dumpImageToFile(event.getImage());
        }
    }
    private String dumpImageToFile(BufferedImage image) {
        try {


            String outputFilename =  "PATH_AND_NAME" + ".png";
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(outputFilename));

            //Redimensiona a imagem 
            BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(outputFilename));
            int type = originalImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();

            BufferedImage resizeImagePng = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
            ImageIO.write(resizeImagePng, "png", new File(outputFilename));

            return outputFilename;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type){
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
    g.dispose();
    return resizedImage;
 }
```

Download:
http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler